# How do we prove this inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, summation, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, muirhead-inequality

Suppose $a,b,c > 0$. Prove that
$$\frac{a^2}{b^2} +\frac{b^2}{c^2} + \frac{c^2}{a^2} \geq \frac ab + \frac bc + \frac ca.$$
I've tried multiplying everything by the denominator and then I tried to use the rearrangement inequality, but it didn't yield the result I was looking for. I couldn't really think of anything else to do.

Comment: Welcome to mathematics SE. What have you tried? What are your thought on the problem?

Comment: Reformatted using MathJax. Also, note you must assume strictly positive, not just nonnegative, since each of these variables appears as a denominator (corrected).

Comment: @Matthew I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: Well, I've tried multiplying everything by the denominator and then I tried to use the rearrangement inequality, but it didn't yield the result I was looking for. I couldn't really think of anything else to do. Could you show me what you did @MichaelRozenberg ?

Answer (score 4):

*Just another way:*
Let $x = a/b, y = b/c, z=c/a$, so that $xyz=1$.  Then we need to show $x^2+y^2+z^2\geqslant x+y+z$.  It is enough to show that $f(t)=t^2-t-\log t \geqslant 0$, which is easy as its only minimum is when $f(t=1)=0$.

Comment: By AM-GM, $x+y+z\geq 3$ so by Cauchy-Schwarz or Rearrangement $$a^2+b^2+c^2\geq \frac 13 (a+b+c)^2 \geq a+b+c.$$

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite LHS as 6 terms, group them like this
$$
\left( \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{a^2}{b^2} + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{b^2}{c^2} \right)+\dots
$$
Then apply AM-GM inequality

Comment: This ansatz does not respect the cyclicity as
$\frac ab =\frac ac\cdot\frac cb\leqslant\frac 12\frac{a^2}{c^2} +
\frac 12\frac{c^2}{b^2}$, hence it's no proof.
Or am I wrong?

Comment: Can you explain further how it doesn't respect cyclicity? I do not see an issue with Vladimir Putin's solution.

Comment: @ClementYung If you proceed with $\frac bc$ and $\frac ca$ analogous to $\frac ab$ in my previous comment, and add up the resulting three inequalities, then you do not get the inequality given in the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Because by AM-GM we obtain: $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{b^2}=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{4a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{c^2}+\frac{c^2}{a^2}\right)\geq\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[6]{\left(\frac{a^2}{b^2}\right)^4\cdot\frac{b^2}{c^2}\cdot\frac{c^2}{a^2}}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{b}.$$
Just another way:

Let $x^3=\frac{a}{b}$, $y^3=\frac{b}{c}$ and $z^3=\frac{c}{a}$.

Thus, $xyz=1$ and we need to prove that
$$x^6+y^6+z^6\geq(x^3+y^3+z^3)xyz,$$ which is true by Muirhead because
$$(6,0,0)\succ(4,1,1).$$

Answer (score 1):

After clearing the denominators we have to prove that
$$a^4c^2+b^4a^2+b^2c^4\geq abc(a^2c+ab^2+bc^2)$$
Now use that $$x^2+y^2+z^2\geq xy+yz+zx$$
This is $$(a^2c)^2+(bc^2)^2+(ab^2)^2\geq a^2cab^2+a^2cbc^2+ab^2bc^2=abc(a^2b+ac^2+b^2c)$$
Since$$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}=\frac{a^2c+ab^2+a^2b}{abc}$$

Comment: I think that right-hand side is not the same.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: We want to show (after clearing the denominators) that a4c2+b4a2+b2c4≥abc(a2c+ab2+bc2). But we only show that a4c2+b4a2+b2c4≥abc(a2b+ac2+b2c). (notice how the squared numbers differ). And also, how do I write in math notation?

Comment: I don't even see the error.

Comment: I'm just saying that the end result: abc ( a^2 b + a c^2 + b^2 c) does not equal what we have at the beginning: abc (a^2 c + a b^2 + b c^2);  since: a^2 b ≠ a^2 c ...